# Connections between Windows 10 and Linux Server

Tags: networking

I run a Windows 10 Laptop and my office has a Linux File Server running Samba.  For some reason, the server is not visible on my network locations, nor can I map a network drive to that files server.  I've tried browsing for the location and mapping the local IP of the server and it comes back telling me that I did not enter a valid location.

Comment: can you `ping` to Linux File Server (IP Address) from your Windows 10 Laptop ? What is the result of the `ping` ?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possible reasons, depending on the details of your environment.

If your Windows 10 installation is originally the "Fall Creators Update" or newer, it has SMBv1 client-side disabled by default. This was motivated by the WannaCry ransomware epidemic, which used a critical vulnerability in SMBv1 protocol.

If your Linux File Server (of unspecified distribution and version?) has not been kept up to date with patches, or has a non-default configuration that has not been reviewed in a long time, it might still have the `server max protocol` setting in its `smb.conf` file defaulting/set to `NT1`, which means SMBv1. Because of the above-mentioned vulnerability, you should be getting rid of SMBv1 sometime last year or so.

All enterprise-grade Linux distributions have long since published updates that allow the use of SMBv2 and/or SMBv3 on any supported versions of the distributions. So if the server is otherwise up to date, it's just a matter of verifying that your `smb.conf` file does not have a stupid `server max protocol` setting, and changing the setting to `server max protocol = SMB3_02` or better if it has.

SMBv1 was long since scheduled to be eventually removed, and the discovery of that vulnerability has, if anything, speeded up the removal schedule.

If your office network environment uses Active Directory, then the discovery of network locations most likely uses AD, and the problem might be that the Linux File Server is failing to register the appropriate DNS records to the AD domain.

If there is no Active Directory, then the discovery of network locations falls back to old NetBIOS style, which might use a WINS server (it's just an additional role on one or more of your server hosts) or it might rely on just broadcasts from each server. In that case, you'll need to verify that ports 137/UDP and 138/UDP are not blocked, both on client and server side.